# How to connect to Matrikon OPC simulation server using Utgard

Tags: opc

On my desktop, I have downloaded and installed the Matrikon OPC Simulation server and on the left panel I have Localhost '\mycomputername' and below that I have Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1 and in the left below panel it says server connected and state as running. I have added a tag in Group0-> Random.ArrayofReal8 and the value is changing. I copied the clsid from the server properties.

Now on the same desktop, I have eclipse open and have the code from Utgard from this link
https://openscada.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OP/pages/6094892/HowToStartWithUtgard

what do I fill in for the

```
ci.setHost("Localhost");
ci.setDomain("");
ci.setUser("");
ci.setPassword("");
//ci.setProgId("Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1");
ci.setClsid("F8582CF2-88FB-11D0-B850-00C0F0104305"); 
final String itemId = "Random.ArrayOfReal8";
```

What would I need to fill in for the host, domain, user and password? Since I am running this from the same laptop, what would the user name and password be. Also what would the host and domain be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my computer name as hostname and the domain and user id and passwd of the desktop and it worked(the tag values are looking weird but will ask that in another question). Sorry for the question..was confused if running on the same desktop, why I would need to provide these crenendtials..thought the simulation software had some credentials which I have to provide.